# Setting Java properties programmatically in Matlab

Tags: java, matlab

I use the file `java.opts` to change Java startup options when launching Matlab. For example, this file might contain a line such as `-Dsun.java2d.xrender=false` which is equivalent to running the following command in Java:

```
System.setProperty("sun.java2d.xrender","false");
```

How can I set this programmatically in Matlab?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After typing up the question I thought to try the following, which worked!

```
java.lang.System.setProperty('sun.java2d.xrender','false');
```